# jQuery $.data('n') returning blank, but $.attr('data-n') gets value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**A third party javascript library** has added data-attributes to an element relating to a tooltip feature as follows:

```
<i id="button1" data-tooltip="xyz-tooltip"></i>
```

*(To make it doubly clear this is not rendered in the document at load time)*

The element is the button that triggers the tooltip, they also append an actual tooltip to the document with an ID that matches the contents of data-tooltip (which I want to find)

I am using jQuery and assumed I could always get at that data using:

```
var theTooltip = $("#button1").data("tooltip");
```

But in my case `theTooltip` is `""`. However I *can* get it using:

```
var theTooltip = $("#button1").attr("data-tooltip");
```

Under what circumstances would the first method not work? Is it perhaps because the element didn't have those attributes (they are not rendered on the server) when jQuery was initialised?

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ygmjpb9v/. Both examples work fine. Please edit the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You haven't replicated it as described, the data-attribute was added dynamically by a third party JavaScript library. I specified that it is *not* in the original rendered document.

Comment: Still works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ygmjpb9v/2/

Comment: Well then look at the plugin and see how they add it. These all work with the code you've shown so we cannot replicate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ygmjpb9v/4/, https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ygmjpb9v/6/. The point here is that if it's not working for you then there's some underlying reason which your question does not cover.

Comment: The point I'm making is that there isn't really one - assuming you are making the calls at the correct times. Also, the question isn't 'perfectly clear' as you've not stated which third party tooltip library you're using. This is also why I asked for you to create a working example of the problem in the question.

Comment: I thought there wasn't one either but here we are. The library is Zurb Foundation. I have researched this and there are problems with its tooltip feature, so it needs to be inelegantly hacked in order to change the contents of it. My problem is solved easily using `attr()`. Here I am simply interested to learn about how it might happen that a js-rendered data attribute would not appear in that element's data. It evidently can happen. But I can't realistically replicate the whole thing without spending a very long time because it is specific to my application and their library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that `$.data()` has been written previously but then the *visible* data-attribute is written to something else. The visible data attribute is then no longer retrieved by `$.data()`

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sp2d74y1/1/

Comment: That makes sense. Glad you got to the bottom of it. It's very weird that Zurb would be doing that, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. If anything your comments drove me to prove it could happen! :) And yes I have no idea why they would do that. Bad code.